# OpenMP parallel for with vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, openmp

I have a fixed-size 2D matrix with size W x H, each element in the matrix is a std::vector. The data is stored in vector of vectors with linearized index. I'm trying to find a way to concurrently fill the output vector. Here is some code to indicate what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

struct Vector2d
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

double generate(double range_min, double range_max)
{
    double val = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return range_min + val * (range_max - range_min);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    // generate input data
    std::vector<Vector2d> points;
    size_t num = 10000000;
    size_t w = 100;
    size_t h = 100;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        Vector2d point;
        point.x = generate(0, w);
        point.y = generate(0, h);
        points.push_back(point);
    }

    // output
    std::vector<std::vector<Vector2d> > output(num, std::vector<Vector2d>());
    std::mutex mutex;

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        const Vector2d point = points[i];
        size_t x = std::floor(point.x);
        size_t y = std::floor(point.y);
        size_t id = y * w + x;
        mutex.lock();
        output[id].push_back(point);
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the code is much slower with openmp enabled. I found some example to fill std::vector using reduction, but I don't know how to adapt it to vector of vectors. Any help is appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete, working program that we can cut and paste.

Comment: @JiveDadson Sure, modified.

Comment: I suspect it is using a lot of time locking and unlocking the mutex. A mutex is a heavyweight that requires going into system mode.  Try using a condition variable. A good implementation will probably system calls when possible. You could also try spinning on a test-and-set.

Comment: Can you modify it so it does not require <Eigen/Eigen>.  i don't even know what Eigen is.  All we need is Vector2d.

Comment: Modified(remove Eigen/Eigen). Yes, it takes a lot of time on the mutex things. I'm not sure how to use a condition variable on that. Could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: I tried using a condition_variable, in the hopes that the implementation would use a spin-lock before resorting to a system call.  No joy. On VC++ it was actually slower.  You have another problem besides the mutex, namely false sharing. OpenMP tasks could solve that by giving each task its own vector, and combining them at the end. My compiler does not do OpenMP tasks.  Could you use std::thread instead?

Comment: The generate() function is probably so fast that any kind of thread synchronization is going to be too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you could do to improve the performance:

I would preallocate the second vector holding the `Vector2d` class, because every time you `push_back` a new `Vector2d` and the [capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) of the `std::vector` is exceeded, it is going to reallocate. So if you do not care having initialized `Vector2d`s in your `std::vector` I would simply use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vector2d> > output(num, 
               std::vector<Vector2d>(num, Vector2d(/*whatever goes in here*/)));
```

Then in your for loop, you coul access the elements in the second vector via `operator[]`, which allows you to get rid of the lock.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    const Vector2d point = points[i];
    size_t x = std::floor(point(0));
    size_t y = std::floor(point(1));
    size_t id = y * w + x;
    output[id][i] = num;
}
```

Though I'm not sure, the before-mentioned way works with what you want to do. Otherwise you could [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the storage for each `std::vector<Vector2d>`, which would leave you with your initial loop:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vector2d> > output(num, std::vector<Vector2d>());
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    output[i].reserve(num);
}

#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    const Vector2d point = points[i];
    size_t x = std::floor(point(0));
    size_t y = std::floor(point(1));
    size_t id = y * w + x;
    mutex.lock();
    output[id].push_back(point);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Which means you get rid of the vector re-allocation, but you still have the mutex...

Comment: Thanks for the example! But there is one problem, in my case, the input point number is so huge. If I preallocate the memory, it will consume a large mount of memories. Consider that in each cell of the matrix, one point will appear no more than once, do you think it's possible to use std::vector<std::unordered_set<Vector2d> > to solve it?

Comment: Ahh, you're right the input number is way too big... I don't think `std::unordered_set ` will help here, as insertion normally takes longer then `push_back` (as `std::unordered_set::insert` compares the keys). I have tried to use the Map/Reduce Pattern and I noticed, that 2 threads filling their own output vector take as long as one thread filling one output vector... Hmm, dunno... I'm out of ideas. Can't help you here. Sorry :(